# Using py2app to create standalone application

Tags: python, executable, py2app

I'm trying to create a standalone app to facilitate editing of photos out of [this](https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/image-background-remove-tool) project which provides a GUI as well.

I'm following all the steps described in the project's `README.md` and I can successfully launch the GUI and edit my photos. After that, when I follow the steps from **[py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)** to create the application, setting the `gui.py` as main, the application crashes.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I have worked with `py2app` in the past but not with such complex projects.

Comment: Hmm. I've never worked with `py2app` before, but I would recommend `pyinstaller` instead - in my opinion, it is easier to use.
What kind of error message are you getting? How does the application crash? Are you sure it's `py2app`, and not your script?
Also, it appears `gui.py` uses multiprocessing. Lots of bundlers have problems with multiprocessing, so you ought to read the documentation on it.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the documentation extensively but cannot figure out what I need to do. The application is created but it crashes on execution with the typical Mac OS  message ''The application quit unexpectedly"